# sql - query to insert a column value if it does not exist in that column

Tags: sql

sql - query to insert a column value if it does not exist in that column

Comment: Your question does not make much sense, can you expand on your requirements?

Comment: i want to insert a value into an row of an  table if it does not exists

Comment: it is `update` query, I guess

Comment: i dont want to update i want to insert a value for example
insert into emp("fruits") values("mango");
this statement has to insert if and only if mango is not present already

Comment: Do you want to set the value in a specific row of a column that holds a NULL or insert a new row if a certain value doesn't exist in a specific column?

Comment: So, something like this: `update ... set fruits = 'mange" where fruits is null`

Comment: Edit your question to fully explain exactly what you want. Examples are helpful.

Comment: Also, are values in the column supposed to be unique?

Comment: The opposite of this?: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/denis_gobo/archive/2008/03/28/5860.aspx

Answer (score 17):

Hm. Do you want a new row? In that case,

```
 IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM emp WHERE fruits = 'mango')
    INSERT INTO emp (fruits) VALUES ('mango')
```

Comment: can u just tell me clearly abt not Exists.
i want to insert a value for example insert into emp("fruits") values("mango"); this statement has to insert if and only if mango is not present already
can u tell me the query for that.

Comment: emp is the table name and fruits is the column name and mango is the value.
Now can u tell me how

Comment: Ok, updated the example. It's the same as valli's first example.

Answer (score 8):

Two ways to do

```
1.IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT fruit FROM emp WHERE fruit='mango') 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO emp(fruit) Values('mango'); 
END 

2.INSERT INTO emp ('mango') SELECT distinct fruit FROM emp WHERE not exists (select fruit from emp as e Where emp.fruit = e.fruit);
```