# Insert into table if a field value do not already exist

Tags: mysql

I want to insert values to a row in my customer table if the Name value I'm providing do not already exist,
After some searching I used this sql query to do it and it does not work :(

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Name FROM customer WHERE Name = 'Riyafa') 
INSERT INTO customer (`Name`, `Address`, `ContactNo`,`Total_amout`)
                      VALUES ('Riyafa', 'ABC', '555','1000');
```

Please instruct me why that is incorrect.

Comment: what errors did you get ?

Comment: In which way does it fail?

Comment: I get SQL syntax error

Comment: Have you tried [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)? What you're typing here is just made up, there's nothing in the MySQL documentation that would support that ever working.

Comment: As you're not in a procedure context `IF` can only be used as a function ...

Comment: I referred: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880514/sql-query-to-insert-a-column-value-if-it-does-not-exist-in-that-column

Comment: No idea which SQL dialect this would be valid in (the mentioned post doesn't tell), but it's not MySQLs dialect for sure ...

A simple INSERT IGNORE would work if you have a UNIQUE key on Name, otherwise you'll have to do a SELECT first, check the result in your application, then conditionally do the insert ... or wrap things up in a PROCEDURE if you need to do it as a single SQL statement

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement is only allowed in stored procedures, functions, and triggers.  One way you can do this is:

```
INSERT INTO customer (`Name`, `Address`, `ContactNo`,`Total_amout`)
    SELECT name, address, contactno, total_amount
    FROM (SELECT 'Riyafa' as name, 'ABC' as address, '555' as contact no, '1000' as total_amount) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM customer c WHERE c.name = t.name);
```

A better approach, however, is to have the database enforce uniqueness on the name.  Start by creating a unique index or name:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_customer_name ON customer(name);
```

Then use a construct such as `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO customer (`Name`, `Address`, `ContactNo`,`Total_amout`)
    SELECT 'Riyafa' as name, 'ABC' as address, '555' as contact no, '1000' as total_amount
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Name = VALUES(Name);
```

The expression `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Name = VALUES(Name)` actually doesn't do anything, but it prevents the `INSERT` from returning an error.