# If record exits in database update else create new record in database in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have 4 databases: sql server, MySql, DB2 and Oracle.
I want to write a script with some new records, 
But for some of the records may exits already.
So if record exits in yjr database update need to perform else create new record in database in sql.

is it possible to write with script rather then procedures ?

Like if record not exit ( create data) else (update data)

I saw multiple links but mostly those are related to procedures only

[sql - query to insert a column value if it does not exist in that column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880514/sql-query-to-insert-a-column-value-if-it-does-not-exist-in-that-column)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/162627/how-to-insert-new-record-in-my-table-if-not-exists

Thank you

Comment: If you are going to work with 4 different database vendors, your easiest way would be to write stored procedures for all of them. That way your application code doesn't need to know the exact details of the sql dialects of each database.

Comment: The ANSI SQL standard operation is called MERGE and it is supported by three of your databases... alas MySQL does not. For easier management, whatever solution you adopt, you may want to use MERGE for SQL Server, DB2 and Oracle, and whatever solution you develop for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

To have a unified cross-RDBMS SQL you might want to create `DUAL` table in SQL Server, MySQL and DB2:

```
CREATE TABLE DUAL (DUMMY VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO DUAL (DUMMY) VALUES ('X');
```

Then for each record you would be able to:

```
UPDATE Table SET Column = 'Value' WHERE PK = 'ID';
INSERT INTO Table (Column, PK)
SELECT 'Value', 'ID' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT '*' FROM Table WHERE PK = 'ID');
```

If creating `DUAL` is not an option the same can be achieved through:

```
UPDATE Table SET Column = 'Value' WHERE PK = 'ID';
INSERT INTO Table (Column, PK)
SELECT 'Value', 'ID' FROM (SELECT Count(*) As DUMMY FROM Table) DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT '*' FROM Table WHERE PK = 'ID');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use store procedures in this case:

```
SET @s = (SELECT IF((SELECT @catID := cat_id FROM category WHERE name = 'cat name' limit 1) > 0,
          'UPDATE STATEMENT','INSERT STATEMENT'));
select @s;
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Hope this will work out.